# Problems extending HotTowel Dataservice to consume REST using restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular, hottowel

I am using Angular and Hottowel for the first time and I wanted to extend the dataservice to leverage the functionality of restangular to provide REST data into the rest of the hottowel app.

I have included restangular and have it making a successful REST get.

I realise that the restangular docs discuss using the promise directly within a controller so i am now wondering whether including it in the dataservice is viable.

The problematic function is getJobs.
Its the only function that uses restangular.
Its defined in dataservice as a function and also added to the dataservice variable to expose it.
It has a matching function in the dashboard controller.
Its also added to the list of promises in the dashboard controller.
I have confirmed the function returns a list of objects within the restangular function.
I get nothing in the dashboard controller even though the promise executes the then clause.

Any guidance gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

Simon

Code below:-

**dataservice.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.core')
    .factory('dataservice',dataservice);

dataservice.$inject = ['$q','Restangular'];
/* @ngInject */
function dataservice($q,Restangular) {
    var service = {
        getPeople: getPeople,
        getMessageCount: getMessageCountXXX,
        getJobs: getJobs
    };

    return service;



    function getJobs() {
        var jobs = [];
        var baseJobs = Restangular.all('jobs');

        baseJobs.getList().then(function(jobs) {
            console.log("Within dataservice.getJobs");
            console.log(jobs);

        });
        return $q.when(jobs);
        console.log("EndofgetJobspost return shouldnt get here");       
    }


    function getMessageCountXXX() { return $q.when(72); }

    function getPeople() {
        var people = [
            {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Papa', age: 25, location: 'Florida'},
            {firstName: 'Ward', lastName: 'Bell', age: 31, location: 'California'},
            {firstName: 'Colleen', lastName: 'Jones', age: 21, location: 'New York'},
            {firstName: 'Madelyn', lastName: 'Green', age: 18, location: 'North Dakota'},
            {firstName: 'Ella', lastName: 'Jobs', age: 18, location: 'South Dakota'},
            {firstName: 'Landon', lastName: 'Gates', age: 11, location: 'South Carolina'},
            {firstName: 'Haley', lastName: 'Guthrie', age: 35, location: 'Wyoming'}
        ];
        return $q.when(people);
    }
}   
})();
```

**dashboard.Controller.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.dashboard')
    .controller('DashboardController', DashboardController);

DashboardController.$inject = ['$q', 'dataservice', 'logger'];
/* @ngInject */
function DashboardController($q, dataservice, logger, api) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.news = {
        title: 'helloWorld',
        description: 'Hot Towel Angular is a SPA template for Angular developers.'
    };
    vm.messageCount = 0;
    vm.people = [];
    vm.jobs = [];
    vm.title = 'Dashboard';


    activate();

    function activate() {
        var promises = [getMessageCount(), getPeople(), getJobs() ];
        return $q.all(promises).then(function() {
            logger.info('Activated Dashboard View');
        });
    }

    function getMessageCount() {
        return dataservice.getMessageCount().then(function (data) {
            vm.messageCount = data;
            return vm.messageCount;
        });
    }

    function getPeople() {
        return dataservice.getPeople().then(function (data) {
            vm.people = data;
            return vm.people;
        });
    }

    function getJobs() {
        console.log("Within getJobs");
        return dataservice.getJobs().then(function (data) {
            vm.jobs = data;
            console.log(data);
            return vm.jobs;
        }, function (reason){
            console.log(reason);
        });
    }
}



})();
```

Relevant part of dashboard.html:-

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="widget wviolet">
                    <div ht-widget-header title="Jobs"
                         allow-collapse="true"></div>
                    <div class="widget-content text-center text-info">
                        <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Category</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="p in vm.jobs">
                                    <td>{{p.name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{p.description}}</td>
                                    <td>{{p.status}}</td>
                                    <td>{{p.category}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget-foot">
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, in your dataservice getJobs() function, you are not returning the jobs list that is coming from ajax call. Change that function with below code.

```
function getJobs() {

        var baseJobs = Restangular.all('jobs');

        return baseJobs.getList().then(function(jobs) {
            console.log("Within dataservice.getJobs");
            console.log(jobs);
            return jobs;

        });
    }
```

Comment: I  was following the same pattern of returning into the promise strucuture that the controller is epxecting ---               return $q.when(jobs);

Comment: If i replace the getJobs function with one that returns just a basic JSON array then it works ok.

Comment: Actually you have to return data that is coming in "then" callback. When you write $q.when(jobs), it is returning [] as data as "then" callback will execute after sometime and before that you are returning [] using $q.when(jobs). So just try to return jobs from then callback as I shown in my answer.

Comment: every promise success handler should return something. And whatever you return from handler will be passed as parameter to next success handler. If you handling success, then return something. In your case its not returning anything, so next subsequent success handler will have undefined as parameters.

Comment: ok - i got it working - patently didnt understand that i needed to return the success handler and then have that return an object. Thanks to you both